# What the difference between unsigned short int and unsigned int or unsigned short?

Tags: c++, int, unsigned, short

According to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types you can use unsigned short type or unsigned short int type. But what the difference between them? I know what is unsigned short and I know what is unsigned int but what does unsigned short int mean? Is it short or is it int?

Comment: `unsigned short int` means exactly the same thing as `unsigned short`.

Comment: Just as `short int` means exactly the same as `short` and `unsigned int` means exactly the same as `unsigned`

Comment: The `short` indicates a smaller minimal range than `int`.  The integral types in C and C++ go by range, not necessary by size.  If you believe your program doesn't need the range of an `int`, then use a `short int`.  If you want specific size, see int16_t or int32_t.

Comment: _"I know what is unsigned short [..] but what does unsigned short int mean?"_ Ehm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unsigned short` and `unsigned short int` refer to exactly the same datatype and are interchangeable.

Comment: unsigned int though is not necessarily the same as unsigned short (the title asks about that one too)

Answer (score 2):

> *"but what does `unsigned short int` mean? Is it `short` or is it `int`?"*

There's no difference. It's an `unsigned short`, actually the `int` keyword is optional for `short` or `long` declarations. The `unsigned` keyword may applied to ***all*** of these type declarations, and makes them just `unsigned`.